# How can I make an empty/invisible bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap

Is there any way to create a bitmap that, when you use it in on a view in the **setImageBitmap** method, it looks like no image was actually set at all?

EDIT: To clarify, I want the bitmap to not be visible, or it can be visible, as long as its nothing, as long as the user cant see it im happy.

EDIT2: I cannot use setVisibility because my ImageView also has a setBackground attribute that I want to remain visible. If I set the view to invisible, the background AND the bitmap image are affected, and I dont want that. I only want the bitmap image to be invisible.

Comment: use `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`

Comment: Can you explain your question in more detail? What do you mean by `looks like no image was actually set at all`??

Comment: you must figure out what you really want, an invisible takes no space on the screen and empty is just like a placeholder

Comment: INVISIBLE means the view is measured but not drawn, so there will be space reserved for it in the parent layout. GONE means the view is neither measured nor drawn.

Comment: OK so use My first Comment @Clay

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan I cant, it says setVisibility is undefined for type bitmap

Comment: yes, where you want see your bitmap? in `imageView`? so use `imageview.setV....`

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan Please see my second edit, sorry for not being more specific >.<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call `imageView.setImageBitmap(null)` to remove the current image and keep the background.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a 1x1 pixel bitmap which is nothing but empty canvas (in photoshop perhaps), then use the [draw9patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) tool to make it stretch.

EDIT: If you just need it not to draw, you can call `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` on the view like so:

```
imageView.setVisibilty(View.INVISIBLE)
```

Comment: Isn't there any easier, programmatic way of just creating a bitmap that is transparent or something?

Comment: What's easier than this? Stick it in res/drawable-nodpi and refer to it like `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty)`. Or just call `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` on the view itself -- this will cause the view to not be drawn, but it will still be measured and therefore will still occupy the same space on screen.

Comment: Well I dont know how to make a bitmap with nothing but an empty canvas, and I dont have photoshop, and I have no idea what draw9patch is. I was just hoping for a very simple solution. Sorry if I sound stupid. Ill accept your answer if no one else gives an easier solution

Comment: There are some free alternatives to photoshop, like GIMP. Create a new file, set it's size to 1x1, and save. Then you run the draw9patch tool, which is part of the android SDK bundle you downloaded (it's an executable file in `<your-android-sdk-directory>/tools`). Put a little black dot on all four sides of the image and save it. Make a new folder under `res` and name it `drawable-nodpi` and put the resulting `.9.png` file there.

Answer (score 1):

[image: It is a 50X50 transparent image created in photoshop download and use it] ← Image is here

above is a 50X50 transparent image created in photoshop download and use it,